# How to add one more measure in MDX where clause?

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

Below query is perfectly working and bringing rolling 12 months data for selected measure. Now how do I add one more measure to same MDX query so that query fetch rolling 12 months for 2 measures?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Working query with single measure

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {LastPeriods(12,[Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21])} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Customer].[CustomerName].[CustomerName].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [CustomerNamedSet] ON COLUMNS
  FROM [CSIS]
  WHERE 
    (
      {[Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21]}
     ,{[Measures].[measure1]}
    )
);
```

[image]

Modified MDX query by adding one more measure in where clause (Not working)

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {LastPeriods(12,[Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21])} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Customer].[CustomerName].[CustomerName].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [customerNamedSet] ON COLUMNS
  FROM [CSIS]
  WHERE 
    (
      {[Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21]}
     ,{
        [Measures].[measure1]
       ,[Measures].[measure2]
      }
    )
);
```

Expected results::

[image]

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! In the `sub-select` you can move the set of measures into the `COLUMNS` section like this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.MEMBERS * 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
 ,[Product].[Category].[Category].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      {
        [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
       ,[Product].[Category].[Bikes]
      }*
      {
        [Measures].[Sales Amount]
       ,[Measures].[Total Product Cost]
      }*
      LastPeriods
      (12
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2011]&[12]
      ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

This produces output like you have specified:

[image]

Do you really need to use a `sub-select`? If not the query could be a lot simpler:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
      {
        [Measures].[Sales Amount]
       ,[Measures].[Total Product Cost]
      }
    * 
      LastPeriods
      (12
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2011]&[12]
      ) ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
   ,[Product].[Category].[Bikes]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Gives the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I have handled this case through drill down action by creating 13 members. All good now.

Comment: @kpsr thanks! You could add your solution as an answer for future reference.

Comment: I have created local measures using with member and add those measures part of drill down actions. Where business is fine with that approach. Once again thank you for your time.